# Вопрос по добавлению элементов в словарь

Tags: python, dict

Вопрос следующий.
Обратил внимание, что при добавлении в словарь "ключ-значение", получаю не полный список вариаций.
Есть код

```
symbol = 'DAI'
voc = {}
voc2 = {}
products = client.get_products()
for product in products['data']:
    if product['q'] == symbol:
        voc.update({product['b']:product['q']})
print(voc)
for key in voc.keys():
    for product in products['data']:
        if product['q'] == key:
            voc2.update({product['b']:product['q']})
print(voc2)
```

`product` выглядит так. Оттуда  мне нужно два значения с `product['b']` и `product['q']` соответственно.

```
{'s': 'LTCNGN', 'st': 'TRADING', 'b': 'LTC', 'q': 'NGN', 'ba': 'Ł', 'qa': '', 'i': 1e-05, 'ts': 1, 'an': 'Litecoin', 'qn': 'Nigerian Naira', 'o': 70550, 'h': 72371, 'l': 68303, 'c': 71838, 'v': 487, 'qv': 34329464.12499, 'y': 0, 'as': 486.26069, 'pm': 'USDⓈ', 'pn': 'USDⓈ', 'cs': 66424629, 'tags': ['pow', 'mining-zone'], 'pom': False, 'pomt': None, 'etf': False}
```

Cловарь `voc` заполняется корректно.
Вывод. Нашел все "ключ-значение" подставив их из  `product['b']` и `product['q']`, в том случае, если `product['q'] == symbol`

```
{'BNB': 'DAI', 'BTC': 'DAI', 'BUSD': 'DAI', 'ETH': 'DAI', 'USDT': 'DAI'}
```

Дальше возникают трудности.
По идее. Итератор должен взять каждый ключ из словаря `voc` и через функцию `client.get_products()` получить все "ключ-значение", у которых ключ из словаря `voc` стоит на месте значения, согласно этому коду.

```
for key in voc.keys():
    for product in products['data']:
        if product['q'] == key:
            voc2.update({product['b']:product['q']})
```

Вывод `voc2`

```
{'AAVE': 'USDT', 'ADA': 'USDT', 'ALGO': 'USDT', 'ALPHA': 'USDT', 'ANKR': 'USDT', 'ANT': 'USDT', 'ARPA': 'USDT', 'ATOM': 'USDT', 'AVA': 'USDT', 'AVAX': 'USDT', 'AXS': 'USDT', 'BAKE': 'BNB', 'BAND': 'USDT', 'BAT': 'USDT', 'BCH': 'USDT', 'BEL': 'USDT', 'BLZ': 'USDT', 'BTT': 'USDT', 'BURGER': 'BNB', 'CAKE': 'BUSD', 'CELR': 'USDT', 'CHR': 'USDT', 'CHZ': 'USDT', 'COCOS': 'USDT', 'COS': 'USDT', 'COTI': 'USDT', 'CREAM': 'BUSD', 'CRV': 'USDT', 'CTK': 'USDT', 'CTSI': 'USDT', 'DASH': 'USDT', 'DGB': 'USDT', 'DIA': 'USDT', 'DOT': 'USDT', 'EGLD': 'USDT', 'ENJ': 'USDT', 'EOS': 'USDT', 'ETC': 'USDT', 'FET': 'USDT', 'FIL': 'USDT', 'FIO': 'USDT', 'FTM': 'USDT', 'FTT': 'USDT', 'HARD': 'USDT', 'HBAR': 'USDT', 'HOT': 'USDT', 'ICX': 'USDT', 'INJ': 'USDT', 'IOST': 'USDT', 'IOTA': 'USDT', 'IQ': 'BUSD', 'JST': 'USDT', 'KAVA': 'USDT', 'KP3R': 'BUSD', 'KSM': 'USDT', 'LTC': 'USDT', 'LUNA': 'USDT', 'MATIC': 'USDT', 'MBL': 'USDT', 'MFT': 'USDT', 'MITH': 'USDT', 'MKR': 'USDT', 'NEAR': 'USDT', 'NEO': 'USDT', 'NMR': 'USDT', 'OCEAN': 'USDT', 'OGN': 'USDT', 'ONE': 'USDT', 'ONT': 'USDT', 'PAXG': 'USDT', 'PERL': 'USDT', 'PROM': 'BUSD', 'RSR': 'USDT', 'RUNE': 'USDT', 'RVN': 'USDT', 'SAND': 'USDT', 'SC': 'USDT', 'SNX': 'USDT', 'SOL': 'USDT', 'SPARTA': 'BNB', 'SRM': 'USDT', 'STMX': 'USDT', 'STX': 'USDT', 'SUSHI': 'USDT', 'SWRV': 'BUSD', 'SXP': 'USDT', 'THETA': 'USDT', 'TROY': 'USDT', 'TRX': 'USDT', 'UNFI': 'USDT', 'UNI': 'USDT', 'VET': 'USDT', 'VTHO': 'USDT', 'WABI': 'BTC', 'WAN': 'USDT', 'WAVES': 'USDT', 'WIN': 'USDT', 'WING': 'USDT', 'WNXM': 'USDT', 'WRX': 'USDT', 'WTC': 'USDT', 'XLM': 'USDT', 'XMR': 'USDT', 'XRP': 'USDT', 'XTZ': 'USDT', 'XVS': 'USDT', 'YFI': 'USDT', 'YFII': 'USDT', 'ZEC': 'USDT', 'ZEN': 'USDT', 'ZIL': 'USDT', 'BNB': 'USDT', 'NULS': 'USDT', 'LINK': 'USDT', 'KNC': 'USDT', 'SNGLS': 'BTC', 'GAS': 'BTC', 'SNM': 'BTC', 'BQX': 'ETH', 'QTUM': 'USDT', 'ETH': 'USDT', 'ZRX': 'USDT', 'OMG': 'USDT', '1INCH': 'USDT', 'ADX': 'ETH', 'AERGO': 'BUSD', 'AGI': 'BTC', 'AION': 'USDT', 'AKRO': 'USDT', 'AMB': 'BTC', 'APPC': 'BTC', 'ARDR': 'USDT', 'ARK': 'BTC', 'ASR': 'USDT', 'AST': 'BTC', 'ATM': 'USDT', 'AUDIO': 'USDT', 'BCD': 'BTC', 'BCPT': 'BTC', 'BEAM': 'USDT', 'BNT': 'USDT', 'BOT': 'BUSD', 'BRD': 'ETH', 'BTCST': 'USDT', 'BTG': 'BTC', 'BTS': 'USDT', 'BZRX': 'USDT', 'CDT': 'ETH', 'CELO': 'USDT', 'CKB': 'USDT', 'CND': 'BTC', 'COMP': 'USDT', 'CTXC': 'USDT', 'CVC': 'USDT', 'DATA': 'USDT', 'DCR': 'USDT', 'DLT': 'BTC', 'DNT': 'USDT', 'DOCK': 'USDT', 'DOGE': 'USDT', 'DREP': 'USDT', 'DUSK': 'USDT', 'ELF': 'ETH', 'EVX': 'BTC', 'FIRO': 'USDT', 'FLM': 'USDT', 'FOR': 'BUSD', 'FUN': 'USDT', 'GLM': 'ETH', 'GO': 'BTC', 'GRS': 'BTC', 'GRT': 'USDT', 'GTO': 'USDT', 'GVT': 'BTC', 'GXS': 'USDT', 'HIVE': 'USDT', 'HNT': 'USDT',
'IDEX': 'BUSD', 'IOTX': 'USDT', 'IRIS': 'USDT', 'JUV': 'USDT', 'KMD': 'USDT', 'LIT': 'USDT', 'LOOM': 'ETH', 'LRC': 'USDT', 'LSK': 'USDT', 'LTO': 'USDT', 'MANA': 'USDT', 'MDA': 'BTC', 'MDT': 'USDT', 'MTH': 'BTC', 'MTL': 'USDT', 'NANO': 'USDT', 'NAS': 'ETH', 'NAV': 'BTC', 'NBS': 'USDT', 'NEBL': 'ETH', 'NKN': 'USDT', 'NXS': 'BTC', 'OAX': 'BTC', 'OG': 'USDT', 'ONG': 'USDT', 'ORN': 'USDT', 'OST': 'ETH', 'OXT': 'USDT', 'PHB': 'BTC', 'PIVX': 'ETH', 'PNT': 'USDT', 'POA': 'BTC', 'POLY': 'BTC', 'POWR': 'ETH', 'PPT': 'BTC', 'PSG': 'USDT', 'QKC': 'ETH', 'QLC': 'ETH', 'QSP': 'ETH', 'RCN': 'BTC', 'RDN': 'BTC', 'REEF': 'USDT', 'REN': 'USDT', 'RENBTC': 'ETH', 'REP': 'USDT', 'REQ': 'BTC', 'RIF': 'USDT', 'RLC': 'USDT', 'ROSE': 'USDT', 'SCRT': 'ETH', 'SFP': 'USDT', 'SKL': 'USDT', 'SKY': 'BTC', 'SNT': 'ETH', 'STEEM': 'ETH', 'STORJ': 'USDT', 'STPT': 'USDT', 'STRAX': 'USDT', 'SUN': 'USDT', 'SUSD': 'USDT', 'SYS': 'BUSD', 'TCT': 'USDT', 'TFUEL': 'USDT', 'TNB': 'BTC', 'TOMO': 'USDT', 'TRB': 'USDT', 'TRU': 'USDT', 'TWT': 'USDT', 'UMA': 'USDT', 'UTK': 'USDT', 'VIA': 'BTC', 'VIB': 'ETH', 'VIBE': 'BTC', 'VIDT': 'BUSD', 'VITE': 'USDT', 'WBTC': 'ETH', 'WPR': 'BTC', 'XEM': 'USDT', 'XVG': 'ETH', 'YOYO': 'BTC', 'BAL': 'USDT', 'AUD': 'USDT', 'BCHA': 'BUSD', 'BTC': 'USDT', 'COVER':
'ETH', 'CVP': 'ETH', 'DEXE': 'ETH', 'DF': 'ETH', 'EUR': 'USDT', 'FRONT': 'ETH', 'GBP': 'USDT', 'GHST': 'ETH', 'HEGIC': 'ETH', 'PAX': 'USDT', 'TUSD': 'USDT', 'USDC': 'USDT', 'BETH':
'ETH', 'CMT': 'ETH', 'DENT': 'USDT', 'EASY': 'ETH', 'KEY': 'USDT', 'NCASH': 'ETH', 'NPXS': 'USDT', 'PROS': 'ETH', 'SLP': 'ETH', 'BUSD': 'USDT'}
```

Однако, случайно обнаружил, что там не все пары. Например, там нет пары `'BNB': 'BTC'`

Сделав не хитрый код для проверки

```
products = client.get_products()
for product in products['data']:
    if product['q'] == 'BTC' and product['b'] == 'BNB':
        print(product)
```

Получил искомое значение.
Вывод с кода

```
{'s': 'BNBBTC', 'st': 'TRADING', 'b': 'BNB', 'q': 'BTC', 'ba': '', 'qa': '฿', 'i': 0.01, 'ts': 1e-07, 'an': 'BNB', 'qn': 'Bitcoin', 'o': 0.0017943, 'h': 0.001915, 'l': 0.0017188, 'c': 0.0018349, 'v': 1701806.52, 'qv': 3092.95504162, 'y': 0, 'as': 1701806.52, 'pm': 'BTC', 'pn': 'BTC', 'cs': 152665937, 'tags': ['pos', 'mining-zone'], 'pom': False, 'pomt': None,
'etf': False}
```

Почему его не в словаре `voc2`?
Возможно, я неправильно заполняю словарь и использую неверный метод `voc2.update`.
UPD. Видимо, ключ не может быть несколько раз одинаковый в словаре. У меня только такое предположение. Следует заменить конструкцию и не использовать словарь?

Comment: Ключи в словаре _уникальны_. Это не предположение, это азы.

Comment: Что в таком случае делать? Что использовать?

Comment: я думаю, вам стоит задуматься об использовании табличного формата данных. например, pandas или что-то в этом роде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение через словарь и список.

```
symbol_pair = 'DAI'
voc = {}
voc2 = []

products = client.get_products()
for product in products['data']:
    if product['q'] == symbol_pair:
        voc.update({product['b']:product['q']})
for key in voc.keys():
    for product in products['data']:
        if product['q'] == key:
            voc2.append([product['b'], product['q']])
```